# How to prevent unexpected redirects from https:// to http://

Tags: cakephp, ssl, cloudcontrol

I'm running an web application that I developed using CakePHP(1.3) on cloudControl.

Using their piggyback SSL, I can access the app fine via `https://` but all redirects go to `http://`.

If I manually change the url, I can access everything via `https://` but this only persists until the next time a redirect is issued, and then I'm back on `http://`.

This doesn't happen in my local environment, so I'm wondering if it's something to do with cloudControl, or the piggyback SSL.

How can I prevent being unexpectedly redirected from `https://` to `http://`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Define FULL_BASE_URL

The load balancer of cloudController probably listens to https requests and forwards them to your application server over http - possibly setting a `X-Forwaded-Proto` header. This is a typical setup so that only the external request bears the overhead of ssl encryption.

Because it's actually on a http connection that the server receives, any absolute urls generated by the router, such as [when a redirect is issued](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/controller/controller.php#L721), will use `http://` by default, and not `https://`, as that is the protocol by which the application server is being accessed.

To override this, define the url to use as the absolute root of the app so that [it is used for all absolute urls](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/router.php#L881-L883).

i.e. put the following in the application bootstrap:

```
define('FULL_BASE_URL', 'https://example.com');
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just tried it and it works perfectly. Thanks!